# Extract days digits present in string and find days digits between extracted days digits in r

Tags: r, string

I want to extract days digits present in string and find all consecutive digits between that range of digits(range days included)  into a list.
Days digit occur after `between day`.  Appreciate if anyone could suggest the easy way out.

```
strng1 <- 'At 00:00 AM, 07:00 AM, 12:30 PM and 07:00 PM, between day 26 and 31 of the month, only in March, June, September, and December  and  At 00:00 AM, 07:00 AM,12:30 PM and 07:00 PM, between day 1 and 14 of the month, only in January, April, July, and October'
strng2 <- 'At 00:00 AM, 07:00 AM, 12:30 PM and 07:00 PM, between day 26 and 14 of the month'
```

Expecting the result to be in list like: for `strng1` `"1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30" "31"` 
for `strng2` `"14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26"`

Comment: I don't understand how you got the posted output. In `strng1` there is `"between day 26 and 31 of the month"` and `"between day 1 and 14 of the month"`. Why that output?

Comment: @RuiBarradas-  Its not the output i got .. i'm expecting the output to be like that.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I believe from `strng1` you get to the output by extracting the date ranges and creating sequences `c(seq(1, 14), seq(26, 31))`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.
The main function is `seqDigits`. It starts by getting a list of vectors, each of them with the digits between the strings `"between day"` and `"of the month"`. Then it produces the sequences of digits with `Reduce/':'` and outputs them sorted.

```
auxfun <- function(s){
  f <- function(.s){
    m <- gregexpr("\\d+", .s)
    regmatches(.s, m)
  }
  m <- gregexpr("between day \\d+ and \\d+ of the month", s)
  s <- regmatches(s, m)
  sapply(unlist(s), f)
}

seqDigits <- function(X){
  y <- auxfun(X)
  d <- lapply(y, function(x){
    Reduce(':', as.numeric(x[2]), as.numeric(x[1]))
  })
  sort(unname(unlist(d)))
}

seqDigits(strng1)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 26 27 28 29 30 31
seqDigits(strng2)
# [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative to Rui's answer essentially via `strsplit`:

```
get_date_range <- function (strng1){
  s <- unlist(strsplit(strng1, 'between day '))[-1]
  .starts <- as.integer(gsub('^(\\d+) and (\\d+).*', '\\1', s, perl = TRUE))
  .ends <- as.integer(gsub('^(\\d+) and (\\d+).*', '\\2', s, perl = TRUE))
  out_list <- Map(f = `:`, .starts, .ends)
  out_vec <- sort(unlist(out_list))
  return (out_vec)
}

# Test
get_date_range(strng1)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 26 27 28 29 30 31
get_date_range(strng2)
# [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

Basically we first split the string using `between day` as split and then proceed to extract the starting and ending indices using the pattern `^\\d+ and \\d+.*` and with it create the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

one very untidy way:

```
a = gsub(".*?(day (\\d+) and (\\d+)\\D+).*?(?1)*",'\\2:\\3,',c(strng1,strng2),perl=T)
sapply(parse(text=sub('(.*),$','c(\\1)',a)),function(x)sort(eval(x)))
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 26 27 28 29 30 31

[[2]]
 [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```